# Permission denied error when executing shell script via GitLab CI/CD

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have not used Linux or Gitlab much so this could be a newbie question. ( I have searched online for the same issue)
In a gitlab pipeline I just want to execute a shell script. The runner is linux based runner using  "docker+machine" executor.
I am  getting `Permission denied` when try to execute the script

**GitLab Pipeline**

```
init-job:
  image: "docker.mycompany/templates/terraform"
  stage: build
  script:
    - ls
    - whoami
    - uname -r
    - ./mydeploy.sh
```

**runner output**

[image]

**mydeploy.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "this is from shell script"
```

**UPDATE 1**
after changing the pipeline job to use
`chmod +x mydeploy.sh` It does not throw error, however it does not  execute the script as well. The echo in the .sh script should output the text.

[image]

Comment: Most likely dont have execute permission on that file `chmod +x mydeploy.sh`

Comment: see my update 1

Comment: you still need to run the file afterwards. `chmod +x mydeploy.sh` wont run the file it just adds the execution bit. So after running that command then you should be able to run `./mydeploy.sh`

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
git update-index --chmod=+x mydeploy.sh
git ls-files --stage # you can check permissons
git commit -m "Executable!"
```

[docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index) for `git update-index`

Comment: Not sure what this issue has to do with git?

Comment: Not cool have chmod +x in your cicd, so if you update permission with this git command, and commit changes, you don’t need to add chmod command in your .gitlab-ci.yml, your script already will be executable